# my.cnf doesn't work in my server

Tags: mysql, percona, settings, my.cnf

now i am using percona server 5.6 on CentOS 6.5.
I wanna change query cache setting.

I tried to change setting /etc/my.cnf.
but it didn't applied.
To investigate whether my.cnf is read correctly,all my.cnf file was deleted and the reboot mysql.
When all my.cnf files could not be found, although the error should occur, it rebooted normally. 
can somebody help me please? Thank you in advance,

> [root@www3216gj ~]# updatedb
>   [root@www3216gj ~]# locate *.cnf
>   /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf
>   /usr/share/doc/Percona-Server-server-56-5.6.17/my-default.cnf
>   /usr/share/percona-server/my-default.cnf
>   /var/lib/mysql/auto.cnf
>   [root@www3216gj ~]# service mysql restart
>   Shutting down MySQL (Percona Server).. SUCCESS! 
>   Starting MySQL (Percona Server). SUCCESS!<-- WHY? 
>   [root@www3216gj ~]# mysql --help --verbose | grep my.cnf
>   order of preference, my.cnf, $MYSQL_TCP_PORT,
>   /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf

Comment: did u check the log files?

Comment: yes i checked log file,but there is no error in particular.

Comment: Do you have a `/etc/my.cnf` file?

Comment: yes i have my.cnf backup file

Comment: maybe this can help you to determine which file is being used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580331/mysql-how-to-determine-which-config-file-is-being-used

Comment: i tried strace.

Comment: stat("/etc/my.cnf", 0x7fffd8b676b0)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/etc/mysql/my.cnf", 0x7fffd8b676b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/etc/my.cnf", 0x7fffd8b676b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/root/.my.cnf", 0x7fffd8b676b0)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/root/.mylogin.cnf", 0x7fffd8b676b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: i expect in this case, mysql is not start.

Comment: What do you get when you run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_log_file_size';` ?

Comment: the result is "innodb_log_file_size 50331648"